# How to write "Drop index xxx if exists" in spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I don't see a way to do so, could anyone know how to archive in spanner?

```
drop index testindex1 if exists
```

Our scenario:
On day 10, we created an index testindex1, and this change (schema file) may get deployed to some or all production environments
On day 30, we decided we actually don't need testindex1, so we would like to drop it if it is there. We are not sure which production databases it has been created in.
Is there a way to ignore the not-found error in the middle when running a batch of DDL statements?

Answer (score 0):

`DROP ... IF EXISTS` is not supported in Cloud Spanner.

What is the use case of this? Can you ignore the not-found error from the drop?

Comment: updated the scenario

Comment: Can you run the drop index DDL alone instead of a batch? You can specify "--ddl" when you run it from gcloud: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/spanner/databases/ddl/update

Answer (score 0):

From the [Spanner documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#drop-index):

```
DROP INDEX [ IF EXISTS ] index_name
```